# In Java does a data type like this exist?

Tags: java

I found this in redis and was trying to see if there was anything similar in Java.  Say I have the following data:

```
3:1
3:2
3:3
4:1
```

As you can see non of the data points on their own are unique but the combination is unique.  There is a command in redis:

```
sadd 3 1 2
sadd 3 3
sadd 4 1
```

That would give me a something like this:

```
3 -> 1, 2, 3
4 -> 1
```

By doing something like `smembers 3`(this would return everything for 3) or `smembers 3 2`(this would return if the subvalue exists).

I'm wondering what the closest I can get to this functionality within Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Guava [`MultiMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface does exactly this. Note that it's up to the particular implementation whether it allows duplicate `<K,V>` pairs. It sounds like you're after one where the K,V pairs are always unique. If so, have a look at the [`HashMultimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) class.

---

However, if you want to roll your own, you're probably looking for a combination of [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html): `Map<Integer,Set<Integer>>`

When you add (key, value) elements to the map:

1. First check to see whether the key is in there. If not, you'll need to add an empty `Set<Integer>`.
2. Then, do `map.get(key).put(value);`

When you want to retrieve all elements with a specific key:

1. `do map.get(key)` and iterate over the result

When you want to see if a specific key/value pair is in there:

1. do `if(map.containsKey(key) && map.get(key).contains(value))`

For extra credit, you could implement all of this inside a wrapper. The [`ForwardingMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html) from guava might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own class MultivalueMap like this:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MultiValueMap<T1, T2> {

    public Map<T1, List<T2>> map = null;

    public MultiValueMap(){
        this.map = new HashMap();
    }

    public void putList(T1 key, List<T2> list){

        map.put(key, list);
    }

    public void put(T1 key, T2 value){
        List<T2> list = null;
        if(map.get(key) == null){
            list = new ArrayList<T2>();
            map.put(key, list);
        }
        else {
            list = map.get(key);
        }
        list.add(value);
    }

    public List<T2> get(T1 key){
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public Set<T1> keySet(){

        return map.keySet();
    }

    public Map getMap(){

        return this.map;
    }

    public boolean contains(T1 key, T2 listValue){

        List<T2> list = map.get(key);

        return list.contains(listValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing directly built into Java. You could use something like a

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>
```

to store the relationships. This kind of construct is discussed in the [Java tutorial on the `Map` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html). You could also use something like Guava's [`MultiMap<Integer, Integer>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia:

> In its outer layer, the Redis data model is a dictionary where keys
>   are mapped to values.

In other words, just use a Map to store key value pairs. Note that the Map is only an interface. You will need to create a Map object using subclasses which implement the Map interface e.g, HashMap, TreeMap, etc. I think you're confused between the datastructure itself and the implementation of its methods. Those functions which you mentioned can be easily implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using Collections Framework in Java.

as you are looking for key-value pairs to be stored.

you can use [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)  and [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) in java.

```
Map<Integer ,Set<Integer>>
```